# Using variant variable as input to other variant function

Tags: c++, boost-variant

I am using two different variants where one can hold more types than the other.

```
typedef std::variant<boost::blank, double> EmptyDouble;
typedef std::variant<boost::blank, double, int> EmptyDoubleOrInt;
```

Now i want to use a function having the EmptyDoubleOrInt as parameter. This function works fine for an integer, double or blank, but not for a EmptyDouble type:

```
SomeFunction(EmptyDoubleOrInt input);
```

How can i convert the EmptyDouble to either a blank or double without having to know what type it has. So it will be a correct input for the function?

```
SomeFunction(DoSomething(emptyDouble))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::visit` to construct `EmptyDoubleOrInt` from `emptyDouble`:

```cpp
SomeFunction(std::visit([](const auto& a) -> EmptyDoubleOrInt {
    return a;
}, emptyDouble));
```

Comment: it is a good practice to wrap such things in helper functions: https://godbolt.org/z/G9vxYjK5M